# drupal user relationships

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, relationships

hey all, throwing this one out there... hope it's a simple one.

using the drupal module user relationships i can see my relationships by going to

```
site.com/relationships
```

i need a page that displays the relationships of a different user.

is that available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but something like this might work: site.com/user/uid/relationships

Comment: I never used the module, but the code in `user_relationships_ui_menu()` suggests that Chad is right. To make it perfectly clear: go to `[site.com]/user/[uid]/relationships` where `[site.com]` is your Drupal base url and `[uid]` is the id of the user.

Comment: ahh i was using /user/username/relationships.

/user/[uid]/relationships does work.

any idea how i can get the name to work too?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Realname module to replace the UID in the url: https://drupal.org/project/realname